# Does High Fructose Corn Syrup show up in the sugar value on Nutrition Facts?

Tags: sugar, nutrition, labeling, fructose, sweeteners

I noticed some sodas have a sugar value of say 35g. Then under sweeteners they list Sugar and High Fructose Corn Syrup.

Is the HFCS part of that 35g or is that 35g of actual sugar and then an undisclosed amount of HFCS?